# SelectedValue null in dropdownlist so errow thrown

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu, sqldatasource

This is my code in aspx:

```
 <EditItemTemplate>           
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
         DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" SelectedValue='<%#GetSYSACCID(Eval("SYSACCID"))%>'
         DataTextField="UserName" DataValueField="SYSACCID">
    </asp:DropDownList>
  </EditItemTemplate>
```

DropDownList is inside EditItemTemplate of TemplateField in gridview. The GetSYSACCID is a function defined in aspx.cs. Problem is when `Eval("SYSACCID")` is null, `GetSYSACCID` returns null and so error is thrown. How can I handle this? I know this looks easy but still it's giving me a pain.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: why don't you do this from the code behind, after having databound the dropdownlist ? this would allow you to use a old good `if (yourvalue != null){}`

Comment: Return 0 from `GetSYSACCID` when you get a null.

Comment: @Steve B: I would have loved to do that but this dirty is not developed by me. It is gifted to me by a different employee.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like...

```
SelectedValue='<%# GetSYSACCID(Eval("SYSACCID") == null ? 0 : Eval("SYSACCID"))%>'
```

You have default value to handle null value. e.g.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" AppendDataBoundItems="true"
            SelectedValue='<%#GetSYSACCID(Eval("SYSACCID"))%>' DataTextField="UserName" DataValueField="SYSACCID" >
            <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="---Select---"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: I get this error: "'DropDownList1' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.
Parameter name: value"

Comment: Is your SqlDatasource returning anything? In other words are you trying to set a SelectedValue in an empty list

Comment: @Antony Scott: Are you trying to set a? means what? My SqlDataSource returns a List and they all have values. But databinding expression is selectedvalue sometimes is null that is why I am getting all sort of exceptions.

Comment: @Antony: No the list is returned. It is not empty list.

Comment: @Bob Lee Swagger, sorry i hit the return key instead of backspace on my ipad on-screen keyboard :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SelectedValue='<%# GetSYSACCID(Eval("SYSACCID")) ?? 0 %>'
```

or modify `GetSYSACCID` to `return 0` when you receive null input.